# Ffmpeg generate master playlist file in realtime

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

I have playing with ffmpeg and HLS adaptive encoding, i want to make it somehow to encode one by one resolution and make/update master playlist file in realtime..
Example, when 240p is done master playlist file will be updated and video can be played in 240p while 480p,720p and etc... is still encoding in background.

I have try with this command and actualy this is working fine but not in way as i want...

```
/home/test/ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 
-map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0
-c:v h264 -profile:v main -crf 20 -sc_threshold 0 -g 48 -keyint_min 48 -c:a aac -ar 48000
-filter:v:0 scale="trunc(oh*a/2)*2:240" -maxrate:v:0 856k -bufsize:v:0 1200k -b:a:0 96k  
-filter:v:1 scale="trunc(oh*a/2)*2:480" -maxrate:v:1 1498k -bufsize:v:1 2100k -b:a:1 128k  
-var_stream_map "v:0,a:0,name:240p v:1,a:1,name:480p" 
-hls_time 4 -hls_list_size 0 -master_pl_name master.m3u8 -hls_segment_filename %v_%03d.ts %v.m3u8
```

This command above encoding all resolutions in same time and must finish all before i can watch it.

Any solution to make ffmpeg to encode 240p -> update playlist, encode 480p -> update playlist and etc...

Comment: did you find a solution to this? I have a similar problem to solve: creating a master playlist using the existing streaming playlists.

Answer (score 0):

This is the command I spent days working on a long time ago and kept it saved. It splits the encoding into separate streams for each resolution and simultaneously transcodes them, with each resolution and their output in their respective folders and a master file for them.

```
ffmpeg.exe -threads 4 -filter_complex_threads 4 -vsync 1 -i InputFile.ts -filter_complex 
"[v:0]split=5[s0][s1][s2][s3][s4]; 
[s0]scale=w=1920:h=1080:flags=lanczos,yadif[v0];
[s1]scale=w=1280:h=720:flags=lanczos,yadif[v1];
[s2]scale=w=854:h=480:flags=lanczos,yadif[v2];
[s3]scale=w=480:h=360:flags=lanczos,yadif[v3];
[s4]scale=w=426:h=240:flags=lanczos,yadif[v4]" 
-map "[v0]" -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 23.976 -vcodec libx264 -b:v:0 12M -preset medium -profile:v baseline -keyint_min 24 -level 3.0 -s 1920:h=1080 -g 48 -x264opts no-scenecut -strict experimental -map_metadata -1 
-map "[v1]" -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 23.976 -vcodec libx264 -b:v:1 7.5M -preset medium -profile:v baseline -keyint_min 24 -level 3.0 -s 1280:h=720 -g 48 -x264opts no-scenecut -strict experimental -map_metadata -1 
-map "[v2]" -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 23.976 -vcodec libx264 -b:v:2 4M -preset medium -profile:v baseline -keyint_min 24 -level 3.0 -s 854:h=480 -g 48 -x264opts no-scenecut -strict experimental -map_metadata -1 
-map "[v3]" -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 23.976 -vcodec libx264 -b:v:3 1.5M -preset medium -profile:v baseline -keyint_min 24 -level 3.0 -s 480:h=360 -g 48 -x264opts no-scenecut -strict experimental -map_metadata -1  
-map "[v4]" -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 23.976 -vcodec libx264 -b:v:4 1M -preset medium -profile:v baseline -keyint_min 24 -level 3.0 -s 426:h=240 -g 48 -x264opts no-scenecut -strict experimental -map_metadata -1 
-map a:0 -map a:0 -map a:0 -map a:0 -map a:0 -c:a aac -b:a 96k -af “aresample=async=1:min_hard_comp=0.100000:first_pts=0” 
-f hls -var_stream_map "v:0,a:0 v:1,a:1, v:2,a:2, v:3,a:3, v:4,a:4" 
-hls_wrap 24 -hls_time 10 -master_pl_name master.m3u8 "%PathOfFilesWhereYouWantResult%/vs%v/manifest.m3u8"
```

You can change the arguments to fit your use case, but the format of the command will be the same.